# How to check which form is used to access current form?

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 forms, namely `Form1`, `Form2` & `Form3`.

Both `Form1` and `Form2` are able to access to `Form3`. However, I am going to give **different function** to a button in `Form3` depends which form is used to access `Form3`.

Is anyone free to explain it to me how to code should work? Also, if you guys have link that this question previously answered or better concept, I will highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

*My rough idea*:

```
Public Class Form3
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      If 'user are access from Form1 Then
           'Action if user are access from Form1 here
      Else
           'Action if user are access from Form2 here
      End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this code

```
If Me.Owner.Equals(Form1) Then . . .
```

this way you have tightly coupled objects - Form2 and 1 knows Form3 and Form3 knows 2 and 1. It may be not a problem for you or for now. But in OOP it is a problem, and in the future it may be a problem for your object scalability. Here is OOP approach. Writing from my head, so there could be syntactically incorrect items:

```
Public Interface IFormCanDoSomething
    Sub DoSomething()
    ReadOnly Property FormAction As EnumFormActions 
End Interface

Public Class Form1
    Implements IFormCanDoSomething

    ReadOnly Property FormAction As EnumFormActions Implements IFormCanDoSomething.FormAction
        Get
            Return EnumFormActions.Action1
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub DoSomething() Implements IFormCanDoSomething.DoSomething
        Dim f As New Form3(Me)
        f.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Implements IFormCanDoSomething

    ReadOnly Property FormAction As EnumFormActions Implements IFormCanDoSomething.FormAction
        Get
            Return EnumFormActions.Action2
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub DoSomething() Implements IFormCanDoSomething.DoSomething
        Dim f As New Form3(Me)
        f.Show()
    End Sub
End Class   


Public Class Form3

    Private _owner As IFormCanDoSomething
    Public Sub New(owner As IFormCanDoSomething)
        _owner = owner
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If _owner.FormAction = EnumFormActions.Action1 Then
           'Action if user needs one thing
        ElseIf  _owner.FormAction = EnumFormActions.Action2 Then
           'Action if user needs another thing  here
        ElseIf  _owner.FormAction = EnumFormActions.Action3 Then
           'Action if user needs third thing
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

So what is the gain here? Look at `Button1_Click`. Do you see? - now you can have many forms for which `Form3` needs to perform Action1, or/and many forms that `Form3` needs to perform Action2, etc. This could go farther but for now good enough

Comment: Thanks for your help, really helpful answer! Will try it out and get back to you with feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the Show method, pass the Form as the Owner into it:

```
Form3.Show(Form1)
```

Then reference the Form3 Owner:

```
Public Class Form3
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Me.Owner.Equals(Form1) Then
            'Action if user are access from Form1 here
    ElseIf Me.Owner.Equals(Form2) Then
            'Action if user are access from Form2 here
    End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it! Problem solved.

Comment: Is the line `Else Me.Owner.Equals(Form2) Then` supposed to be `ElseIf Me.Owner.Equals(Form2) Then` ? ie Else**If** ?

Comment: @aneroid Yea, it supposed to be `ElseIf Me.Owner.Equals(Form2) Then`